# Find and display registry empty keys with Powershell

Tags: powershell, registry

How to find and display Windows registry empty keys using Powershell?

Know that `GetChild-Item` can search Registry using `HKLM:\` or `HKCU:\`.

I tried

```
Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\" -Recurse | 
    Where Property -like '' | foreach {
    $_.GetValue("DisplayName")
}
```

but doesn't work.

For empty keys I mean keys that have only the Default value and do not have sub-keys.

Then export to a text file using `>`, analyze the result and delete what is not needed.

Comment: May I ask why you want to delete empty keys? There's actually no need to remove empty keys from the registry. And each key will have at least the standard value

Comment: Yes, for empty keys I mean having the standard value only. I know there's no need to remove but I would like to do nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're looking for registry keys with no subkey and no property - except for the default value. Because both properties are provided when you use `Get-ChildItem` you just have to filter for them:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 'REGISTRY::HKEY_CURRENT_USER' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Where-Object {
        -not $_.SubKeyCount -and
        -not $_.Property
    } | 
        Select-object -Property PSPath
```

It is still a bad idea to remove keys from the registry without the need.

Answer (score 0):

Modified @Olaf solution with `-ExpandProperty` to handle long registry paths and `Name` not to have prefix before registry path

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKCU:', 'HKLM:' -r -ea si |
    Where-Object {
        -not $_.SubKeyCount -and
        -not $_.Property
    } | 
        Select-object -ExpandProperty Name > list_empty.txt
```

Comment: You may even output more than just one property to a CSV file. So you'd be able to use the one needed depending on the further steps you want to process. ;-)